# use FILTER on graph in SPARQL query

Tags: filter, sparql

I have thousands of quads/triples in knowledgebase Allegro Graph. I am using the following SPARQL query to find out the specific graph from knowledge base

```
SELECT ?subject ?predicate ?object ?graph
FROM Named <http://www.abc.com/xyz/abc123graphname>
WHERE {GRAPH ?graph
   {?subject ?predicate ?object .}}
```

This shows all quads that has graph name = http://www.abc.com/xyz/abc123graphname.
But now I want to use FILTER to show only those quads that has graph name  start with abc*.

such as

```
<http://www.abc.com/xyz/abc123graphname>
<http://www.abc.com/xyz/abc425graphname>
<http://www.abc.com/xyz/abc324graphname>
```

Please note that I have many graph names in my knowledge base such as

```
<http://www.abc.com/xyz/abc123graphname>
<http://www.abc.com/xyz/abc425graphname>
<http://www.abc.com/xyz/abc324graphname>
<http://www.abc.com/xyz/xyz123graphname>
<http://www.abc.com/xyz/samplegraphname>
<http://www.abc.com/xyz/vibergraphname>
```

Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can filter on the graph name with some variation on:

```
   { GRAPH ?graph    {?subject ?predicate ?object .}
     FILTER( contains(str(?graph), "abc") )
   }
```

or use a different string test.  Note the `str(...)`.

Comment: Many Thanks for your reply. Now my query will be SELECT ?subject ?predicate ?object ?graph
FROM Named <http://www.abc.com/xyz/abc123graphname>
WHERE { GRAPH ?graph    {?subject ?predicate ?object .} 
     FILTER( contains(str(?graph), "abc") )
   }   Thsi is working fine but I need to search from all graph. could you please help how I can replace the line   FROM Named <http://www.abc.com/xyz/abc123graphname> with all graph name